# Вызов события из другого потока

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter

Допустим, существует окно tkinter, запущенное в потоке. И в параллельном потоке прослушиваются команды с сервера. Возможно ли из потока прослушивающего команды, сгенерировать события в окне tkinter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, события tkinter без проблем передаются между потоками. К сожалению, нет возможности передать с событием какую-либо нагрузку. Но это легко решается использованием очереди:

```
from functools import partial
import socket
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
import queue

def worker(q, r):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('localhost', 1234))
    s.listen(5)

    # Передаём серверный сокет в очередь,
    # чтобы главный поток мог прервать цикл
    q.put(s)
    while True:
        (c, address) = s.accept()
        # Передаём в очередь адрес подключившегося
        q.put(address)
        # Генерируем событие
        r.event_generate('<<Connection>>', when='tail')
        c.close()


def on_connection(event, q=None, r=None):
    # Получаем данные из очереди
    data = q.get()
    tk.Label(r, text='Соединение с адреса {} и порта {}'.format(*data)).pack()


# Создаём очередь
q = queue.Queue()

# Создаём окно
root = tk.Tk()

# "Передаём" в обработчик ссылки на очередь и окно
handler = partial(on_connection, q=q, r=root)

# Регистрируем обработчик для события подключения клиента
root.bind('<<Connection>>', handler)

# Создаём поток и передаём в него ссылки на очередь и окно
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q, root))
t.start()

# Получаем из очереди серверный сокет
s = q.get()

root.mainloop()
s.close()
```

Comment: в поток можно `daemon=True` передать, чтобы сервер не ждал соединения, когда GUI закрыто.

Comment: в сторону: можно передать данные через `data` параметр, если [напрямую tcl bind команду вызвать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41912004/4279)

Comment: в tcl из других потоков нельзя event generate вызывать. На pypy просто сразу ломается, на других реализациях может быть хуже: может выглядеть как-будто работает, но приводить к трудно воспроизводимым багам из-за использования нескольких потоков. При возникновении проблем с потоками, безопасной опцией является использование root.after в GUI, чтобы периодически проверять очередь на наличие новых элементов -- другие потоки не вызывают методы [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32682520/4279).

Comment: @jfs что-то изменилось с [2003-го года](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-December/197985.html)?

Comment: [конечно](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2013-November/003526.html)

Comment: @jfs спасибо за ссылку, полезно. Вы можете написать правильный ответ? Боюсь, что у меня сейчас есть время только на то, чтобы добавить в начале своего "Ответ устарел, смотри ответ jfs".

Comment: у вас замечательный ответ. Если вариант с `event_generate()` работает для читателя, то он более предпочтительный нежели polling с root.after. Для тех, у кого проблемы возникнут, мои комментарии предлагают альтернативы. Для меня вопрос слишком общий.