# Как обратиться к Tkinter из второго потока?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, tkinter

Есть бот вк, который работает во втором потоке. При написании определённой команды должна выполняться функция, которая связана с Tkinter. Но у меня ничего не выходит, т.к. выходит ошибка: `Calling Tcl from different apartment`. Что с этим делать?

PS Для многопоточности использую модуль `threading`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все библиотеки графического интерфейса не являются потокобезопасными. Соответственно, нельзя напрямую взаимодействовать с компонентами графического интерфейса из потока иного, чем тот, в котором запущен цикл событий. Правильный подход - это обмен событиями между потоками и передача данных через очередь. Пример можно посмотреть [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/786814/204271).

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, агде можно найти полный список всех событий Tkinter? Просто большинство, что встречаются в ответах - нигде нет

Comment: @DGDays типы событий лучше всего смотреть [в исходном коде](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py), список событий клавишь можно посмотреть [в документации](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm).

Comment: спасибо большое)